# How to delete a sub directory of a directory that has deny set for "List folder contents"

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

How would I deleted a sub directory of a directory that has deny for "List folder contents"? The description for the "List Folder/Read Data" permission can be found [here](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-advanced.htm) but I could not find Microsoft documentation on it.

Here is how the directory structure and how the permissions are setup.

```
C:\Temp\A\B\test.txt
```

- A - Has Deny "List folder contents"
- B - Has default privileges before I set A's privileges
- test.txt - Has default privileges before I set A's privileges

Here is the code I have tried with results in the comments for the code. Also above each method I have included a comment stating what values for path I have tried. I never attempted to delete a directory that had children for all these examples. I am either attempting to delete a file or a empty directory.

```
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  static extern bool RemoveDirectory(string lpPathName);

  //C:\Temp\A - Success
  //C:\Temp\A\B - Fail
  private void RemoveDirectoryImpl(string path)
  {
     if (!RemoveDirectory(path))
        //Returns error code 5 "access denied"
        Debug.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
  }

  //C:\Temp\A - Success
  //C:\Temp\A\B - Fail
  private void DirectoryInfoDeleteImpl(string path)
  {
     DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
     //this throws an UnauthorizedAccessException but the directory is empty so it has no read-only files and the directory itself is not read-only.
     directoryInfo.Delete();
  }

  //C:\Temp\A - Success
  //C:\Temp\A\B - Fail
  private void DirectoryDeleteImpl(string path)
  {
     //this throws an UnauthorizedAccessException but the directory is empty so it has no read-only files and the directory itself is not read-only.
     Directory.Delete(path);
  }
```

I can add and delete file in B for some reason. Also I can delete the root directory with the deny "List folder contents" as long as it is empty.

```
  //C:\Temp\A\B\test.txt - Success
  private void FileDeleteImpl(string path)
  {
     //this is successful and does not throw an error.
     File.Delete(path);
  }
```

I did find [Bypass Traverse Checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/bypass-traverse-checking) which was interesting. I confirmed that our group policy settings still have the Everyone group as part of it.

Here is a screen shot of my security tab for the directory too.
[image: Security Tab]

**EDIT 1:**

Using the information @rbmm gave me in the comments I was able to put together this code but it still will not delete the directory. I tried this code after giving myself "List folder contents" and it worked. Nothing errors in this code.

```
  private void BackupPrivilegeDeleteImpl(string path)
  {
     TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokenPrivileges = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
     tokenPrivileges.Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[40];
     IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

     try
     {
        bool success = OpenProcessToken(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, ref token);

        if (!success)
           throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        success = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_BACKUP_NAME, ref tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid);

        if (!success)
           throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        tokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        success = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, false, ref tokenPrivileges, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(tokenPrivileges), IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (!success)
           throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        //Directory always comes back as the value 0xffffffff
        IntPtr directory = CreateFile(path, EFileAccessMasks.Delete, EFileShare.Delete, IntPtr.Zero, ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting, EFileAttributes.DeleteOnClose | EFileAttributes.ReparsePoint | EFileAttributes.BackupSemantics, IntPtr.Zero);
        CloseHandle(directory);

        Debug.WriteLine(success.ToString());
     }
     catch (Win32Exception e)
     {
        tbLastError.Text = e.NativeErrorCode.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
        CloseHandle(token);
     }
  }
```

**EDIT2:**

As per @eryksun request added output from accessschk.

```
C:\Temp\A
  DESCRIPTOR FLAGS:
      [SE_DACL_PRESENT]
      [SE_DACL_PROTECTED]
  OWNER: REDACTED
  [0] ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE: NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_READ_EA
        FILE_TRAVERSE
        READ_CONTROL
  [1] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ADD_FILE
        FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_READ_EA
        FILE_TRAVERSE
        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_WRITE_EA
        SYNCHRONIZE
        READ_CONTROL
  [2] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [3] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: REDACTED
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [4] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: BUILTIN\Administrators
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [5] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: BUILTIN\Users
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS
```

Accesschk v6.12 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
    Copyright (C) 2006-2017 Mark Russinovich
    Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

```
C:\Temp\A\B
  DESCRIPTOR FLAGS:
      [SE_DACL_PRESENT]
      [SE_DACL_PROTECTED]
  OWNER: REDACTED
  [0] ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE: NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_READ_EA
        FILE_TRAVERSE
        READ_CONTROL
  [1] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ADD_FILE
        FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_READ_EA
        FILE_TRAVERSE
        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
        FILE_WRITE_EA
        SYNCHRONIZE
        READ_CONTROL
  [2] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [3] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: REDACTED
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [4] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: BUILTIN\Administrators
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS
  [5] ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE: BUILTIN\Users
          [OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE]
          [CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE]
          [INHERITED_ACE]
        FILE_ALL_ACCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final code for getting the delete to work. Thank you to @eryksun and @rbmm for their help on getting this to work and giving me the correct win32 api calls I needed to make. My biggest issue here was that I was marshaling the LUID on this line `LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeBackupPrivilege", ref tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid)` as a uint and not as a LUID struct. After setting my privileges on the token I was able to use the managed C# delete method for directory since under the hood it is just calling `RemoveDirectory`. Also I started checking if `AdjustPrivileges` was successful based on the bool it returned as well as always using `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0` which really helped debug this.

```
  private void BackupPrivilegeDeleteImpl(string path)
  {
     TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokenPrivileges = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
     tokenPrivileges.Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1];
     IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

     try
     {
        bool success = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, ref token);

        if (!success)
           throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        success = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeBackupPrivilege", ref tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid);

        if (!success)
           throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        tokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        success = AdjustTokenPrivileges(token, false, ref tokenPrivileges, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(tokenPrivileges), IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (!success || Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0)
           throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

        if (!RemoveDirectory(path))
           throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
     }
     catch (Win32Exception e)
     {
        tbLastError.Text = e.NativeErrorCode.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
        CloseHandle(token);
     }
  }
```

Comment: You may as well enable both SeBackupPrivilege (allows `FILE_GENERIC_READ`, `FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE`, and `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` with backup semantics) and SeRestorePrivilege (allows `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE`, `DELETE`, `WRITE_DAC`, `WRITE_OWNER`, and `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` with backup semantics). The latter ensures you can get delete access.

Comment: Also, in a long-running, multi-threaded application, it's a good practice to enable these privileges only temporarily for a given operation and only for the current thread (e.g. `OpenThreadToken` or, if there isn't one, `ImpersonateSelf` and then the latter).

Answer (score 0):

Use `SetAccessControl()` of `DirectoryInfo` to provide access on directory if your application running with admin privilege.

Comment: if we have admin privilege - we need enable `SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE` privilege in token. we not need change folder access

Comment: I am trying to do this without changing any of the privileges on the directory.